# Flutter: RichText / TextSpan: new line on overflow

Tags: flutter, flutter-text

Suppose I have a the following text

```
RichText(
    maxLines: 10,
    softWrap: true,
    text: TextSpan(
        children: [
            TextSpan(
                text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla pulvinar nisi ullamcorper bibendum tempor. Nam a leo commodo lorem pellentesque condimentum. In odio diam, porttitor ac porttitor at, iaculis elementum ipsum. Integer quis nibh et nulla gravida iaculis in eget elit. Integer mattis pretium bibendum. Pellentesque bibendum scelerisque erat. Phasellus vitae sapien diam. Quisque aliquet iaculis elit sit amet luctus. Donec tortor nisl, pulvinar ultrices mi in, ullamcorper luctus odio. Integer viverra magna quis tortor malesuada, vitae porta purus efficitur. Curabitur mollis cursus eros eget posuere.',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
                    fontSize: 20,
                ),
            ),
        ]),
    )
```

This renders the following

[image]

This long text overflows the screen. What I'd like to have is that the text continues on a new line if the space is running out. How can I achieve this? Setting new lines in the 'text' property is not an option (think of different screen sizes or different languages etc)

Comment: I'm not getting any render error for this. even if I wrap it inside a container and give a smaller width to container it's still visible

Comment: You need to set a finite size for a parent of your text widget, set constraints for it or use flexible/expanded if it is for example column or row.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the RichText within Expanded/Flexible.

***NOTE:** Remember that Flexible and Expanded, should only be used within a Column, Row or Flex.*

```
Container(
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Flexible(
        child: RichText(
          maxLines: 10,
          softWrap: true,
          text: TextSpan(
            children: [
              TextSpan(
                text:
                    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla pulvinar nisi ullamcorper bibendum tempor. Nam a leo commodo lorem pellentesque condimentum. In odio diam, porttitor ac porttitor at, iaculis elementum ipsum. Integer quis nibh et nulla gravida iaculis in eget elit. Integer mattis pretium bibendum. Pellentesque bibendum scelerisque erat. Phasellus vitae sapien diam. Quisque aliquet iaculis elit sit amet luctus. Donec tortor nisl, pulvinar ultrices mi in, ullamcorper luctus odio. Integer viverra magna quis tortor malesuada, vitae porta purus efficitur. Curabitur mollis cursus eros eget posuere.',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Expanded widget

```
Expanded(
    child: RichText(
  maxLines: 10,
  softWrap: true,
  text: TextSpan(children: [
    TextSpan(
      text:
          'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla pulvinar nisi ullamcorper bibendum tempor. Nam a leo commodo lorem pellentesque condimentum. In odio diam, porttitor ac porttitor at, iaculis elementum ipsum. Integer quis nibh et nulla gravida iaculis in eget elit. Integer mattis pretium bibendum. Pellentesque bibendum scelerisque erat. Phasellus vitae sapien diam. Quisque aliquet iaculis elit sit amet luctus. Donec tortor nisl, pulvinar ultrices mi in, ullamcorper luctus odio. Integer viverra magna quis tortor malesuada, vitae porta purus efficitur. Curabitur mollis cursus eros eget posuere.',
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        fontSize: 20,
      ),
    ),
  ]),
));
```

It's worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:
Use `\n` between your Text, to Break it apart.

`\n` breaks the line and makes the further next text jump to next line.

example:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \n consectetur adipiscing elit. \n Nulla pulvinar nisi ullamcorper bibendum tempor.
```

will be Compiled as:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit.
Nulla pulvinar nisi ullamcorper bibendum tempor.
```